# How to use f string to divide users input and print out only 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I was trying to figure out a basic python program with f-strings. The problem was to ask user to enter any amount of ounces and then divide the ounces by 2.34. The output should only be a number with 2 decimal places + it can only be 2 lines of code.
This was part of my code:

```
userOunces = input('Enter any amount of ounces to measure something: ')
print(f'This will print out your amount of ounces divided by 2.34: {userOunces/2.34:.2f}')
```

but it came up with an error?
can anybody help me.

Comment: `input` returns a string. In the next line, you're attempting to divide a `str` (userOunces) by a decimal. You'll need to convert userOunces to either an `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
userOunces = float(input("Enter any amount of ounces to measure something: "))
print(f"This will print out your amount of ounces divided by 2.34: {userOunces/2.34:.2f}")
```

`input` returns a string so you are required to read the input as a `float` or `int`. This allows you to divide the input in your f-string. Use `:.2f` to round the number to two decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help on my previous problem!

The new solution is:

```
userOunces = float(input("Enter any amount of ounces to measure something: "))
print(f"This will print out your amount of ounces divided by 2.34: {userOunces/2.34:.2f}")
```

WHY IT WASN'T WORKING BEFORE: because python returned a string which can not be divided by a number. To fix that you either have to put the int or float in front of the input function so python can divide the user number by 2.34.